# How to show global location coordinates

Tags: coordinates

How can I see the global coordinates of a bone?
Blender only show the transform for local coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what you switched from global to local is the setting for *next* transformations, not the current selection coordinate system. An armature bone, imho, can only show its relative (local) _transform_ coordinates respect to the armature itself, ie, the armature's pivot point. Maybe you could try to explain what you're trying to do that doesn't work...

Comment: Later I want to make another bone be in the exact same location of the previous bone. so for that, I would need to know the exact location.

Comment: another bone in the same armature? when you translate the first bone, the armature pivot will remain at the same point as before, and since new bones added with ALT-A are added at 3d cursor location, you'll just need to snap the cursor to the pivot, and then add the bone in that way. If I got what you mean.

Comment: In a different armature, I have two characters at some point they change location with each other.

Comment: Ok, but... so wont'you need the global coords of the armature, instead of the local coords of the bone, as your question asks?

Comment: yes,that is exactly what I want.